# cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError) when launching Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, mysql2

I'm trying to build and launch a Rails 6 container using mysql2 gem. Everything builds fine but when I go to launch the Rails server, I get the error

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require': libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
```

The relevant part of my Dockerfile is where I'd install the native extensions. I'm aware that MariaDB is also an option but I tried those too and got the same error.

```
apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y git openssh-client build-essential pkg-config default-mysql-client default-libmysqlclient-dev libsqlite3-dev ;\
```

I'm using mysql2 (0.5.3) and Rails 6.0.3.6

Anyone have any suggestions? I've probably spent a week on this, your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That error message implies that you're already using MariaDB. Are you able to connect to the database outside of rails for example with  `$ mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name`?

Comment: Nothing comes up when I enter `which mysql` when I shell into the container. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also check this out. It says that theres 'no such file or directory' but mysql2.so is exactly where it's expected

`$ ls /usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/
client.rb  console.rb  em.rb  error.rb field.rb  mysql2.so  result.rb statement.rb  version.rb` Unless it's refering to libmariadb.so not being where it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

In my Dockerfile I had another FROM clause **after** my apt-get install. Doing that reset the scope of the file so those dependencies weren't available at runtime of the Rails server. I removed that and it worked.